# order of numerical approximation of differential equation, when solution is not one-dimensional

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

In Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_methods_for_ordinary_differential_equations, differential equation's $y(t)$ is $\mathbb{R}^d$. However, when describing order of the numerical method, it is said that the method is of order $p$ if truncation error is $O(h^{p+1})$, where $h$ is time step size. As time is $\mathbb{R}$, I do not see how errors defined for $\mathbb{R}^d$. Is it saying that for all entries $a(t)$ in $y(t)$, truncation error is $O(h^{p+1})$?

Answer (score 0):

That article defines the local truncation error as difference between one step of the numerical solution $\Psi$ (starting without error) and the exact solution $y$ 
$$
\delta^h_{n+k} = \Psi \left( t_{n+k}; y(t_n), y(t_{n+1}), \dots, y(t_{n+k-1}); h \right) - y(t_{n+k}) \in \mathbb{R}^d
$$
A function $g(h)$ is $O(h^{p+1})$ for $h \to a$ if there exists some positive constant $M$ with
$$
\lvert g(h) \rvert \le M \, \lvert h^{p+1} \rvert
$$
in some neighbourhood of $a$. For a multidimensional valued function one can take some norm $\lVert . \rVert$ instead of the absolute value $\lvert . \rvert$:
$$
\lVert \delta_{n+k}^h \rVert \le M \, \lVert h^{p+1} \rVert
$$
Due to [norm equivalence](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28Mathematik%29#.C3.84quivalenz_von_Normen) for finite dimensional vector spaces, the particular choice of a norm should not matter, as some positive constant $M$ results.